# start an executable application from resources without saving it somewhere

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

If i have a file ( `appres.exe` ) in the resources of my `VB 2008 Application (myVbApp.exe)`, how can I start from there? I don't want to save it (appres.exe) somewhere else before start, i want only `myVbApp.exe`, no more files.

Comment: Executable files must be stored on disk, a hard Windows requirement.  Do avoid making EXE files pop up from nowhere, neither users, UAC nor virus scanners are thrilled by that.  Just deploy the EXE along with your regular app.  Creating a setup.exe is dead-simple with a Setup and Deployment project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve the EXE from the resources:

```
   Dim l as System.IO.Stream = Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(String.Format("{0}.{1}", "ApplicationProjectName", "YourExeName"))
```

Then save it to temp folder - example method:

```
Private Sub SaveStreamToFile(ByVal p_stream As Stream, ByVal p_fileName As String)
    Dim l_streamWriter As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create(p_fileName)

    Try
        Dim l_bytes(65536) As Byte
        Dim l_offset As Integer = 0
        Dim l_readBytes As Integer

        Do
            l_readBytes = p_stream.Read(l_bytes, 0, 65536)
            l_streamWriter.Write(l_bytes, 0, l_readBytes)

            l_offset += l_readBytes

        Loop While (l_readBytes > 0)
        Debug.WriteLine("Num Of bytes Read: " + l_offset.ToString)

    Catch ex As Exception
       'log error
    Finally
        p_stream.Close()
        l_streamWriter.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now that you got the EXE in a temp folder, you can regulary lunch it using:

```
Process.Start("EXE_PATH")
```

And delete it once the process is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 Dim SetupPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\appres.exe"
            Using sCreateMSIFile As New FileStream(SetupPath, FileMode.Create)
                sCreateMSIFile.Write(My.Resources.yourexefilename, 0, My.Resources.Yourexefilename.Length)
            End Using
            Process.Start(SetupPath)
```