# Embedded resource - how to run it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which language should I pick up: VB.Net or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132403/which-language-should-i-pick-up-vb-net-or-c-sharp)
>   [start an executable application from resources without saving it somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256939/start-an-executable-application-from-resources-without-saving-it-somewhere)

I added an .exe file as an embedded resource, how can I access it, how to start it? Is it possible?

Comment: You already asked this, what's the point of repeating the question?

Comment: What the hey?!  This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8256939 , **Not** [Which language should I pick up: VB.Net or C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132403/which-language-should-i-pick-up-vb-net-or-c-sharp).

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract it to a temporary directory and execute it from there.
You cannot run an arbitrary EXE from memory.

If the EXE is a .Net assembly, you can just load it in memory by calling `Assembly.Load` and then interact with it normally as a referenced assembly.